# Ubuntu 14.04 touch screen not working after latest kernel upgrade

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

I have Dell Inspiron 15R and every thing was working right until yesterday that installed the latest updates (which included a new kernel 3.13.0-33-generic); and the touch screen is not working anymore.

I clues on how to debug this issue and/or collect information to report the bug?